# How to convert string array to integer array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++17

I have a string of non-uniform space separated integers ,I want to do some arithmetic operations on the elements so I have decided to first convert the string to integer array. Below is my approach:

```
    string s;                //let s="1   2 30 54  899 2 7   3 1";
    cin>>s;
    int n=s.length();
    vector<int>arr(n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==' ')continue;
        else{
            arr.push_back(s[i]-'0');
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl; // arr should be{1,2,30,54,899,2,7,3,1};
    }
```

What is wrong in this approach ?

Comment: Please don't add tags of languages not relevant to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong in this approach?

- `operator>>` only extracts until the first encountered character in `std::cin` that satisfies [`std::isspace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace), so `s` could not possibly be initialized to a string containing spaces in your program.
- You assume that the length of the string `n` should be the length of the array. The number of characters is not equal to the number of whitespace-separated values.
- You initialize `arr` to length `n` and then use `push_back()`. You should be default initializing the vector so it starts empty.
- You read each character separately from the string and `push_back()` each digit as a separate element.

You can use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to initialize the string from `std::cin` and [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istringstream) to simplify extracting the formatted integers:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::vector<int> arr;

    for (int i; iss >> i;) {
        arr.push_back(i);
    }

    for(auto& v : arr)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/5Yz7K7sY9)

Answer (score 0):

You 'll loop all elements and convert with `stoi`.
Then put it in the int-array.